# MailCore how to delete a message

Tags: ios, imap, mailcore

When using MailCore, how do I go about deleting a message? I understand that I set an IMAP deleted flag for a `CTCoreMessage` but does that actually cause a message to be deleted by the server? Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use:

```
- (BOOL)setFlags:(NSUInteger)flags forMessage:(CTCoreMessage *)msg;
```

to set the deleted flag

then:

```
 - (BOOL)expunge;
```

These are both methods in CTCoreFolder.

The tricky part comes from determining if the account is GMail and if the user would rather the message gets moved to [GMail]/Trash or actually deleted

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the library you're using, but no, setting the \Deleted flag does not delete the message right away. You will need to use either the [`EXPUNGE`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.3) (usually this is used) or the [`CLOSE`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.2) command to do so (after setting the \Deleted flag). Refer to [RFC3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) for further details about these commands.